# Win 11 Home - DiskPart cannot find vhdx file that's there?

Tags: windows-11, diskpart

I'm trying to do [this](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4699#issuecomment-627133168) and for the command I get:

```
DISKPART> select vdisk file="C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\ext4.vhdx"

DiskPart has encountered an error: The system cannot find the file specified.
See the System Event Log for more information.

There is no virtual disk selected.
```

I don't understand why. The vhdx file is 100% there, and I'm not making a typo as I'm doing a right click->Copy Path

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason this didn't work:

```
DISKPART> select vdisk file="C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\ext4.vhdx"
```

But this did:

```
DISKPART> select vdisk file="C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\ext4.vhdx"
```

Nothing else changed.

I'll never understand Microsoft.

Comment: Does your user name have any unusual characters, e.g., accented letters?

Comment: Yes, was that the issue? Did Microsoft not figure out UTF-8 even up until today??

Comment: It depends, because Windows often automatically ignores accents when indexing, for example. BTW, be very careful using accents in a user name or login, as those characters **might not always be available** on some keyboards or layouts!!

Comment: that's still not an excuse for them to not handle it in 2023...

Comment: "Handle it?" Windows (and Linux and other OS) are taking *verbatim* the user name. If you create a user through the Albanian keyboard, using special characters, and then try to lo on with the Turkmen layout, it might be that those characters are not available, and it is not easy to switch layout if not logged in. Yes, I had that issue in Linux.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik what does handling UTF-8 characters have anything to do with keyboard layouts? When I wrote my DISKPART command, the character I used was absolutely available on the keyboard and the accent is not ignored when I check my username in any menu or the file explorer folders.